# Error : An unknown directory object was requested , when trying to delete local users

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, windows-7, directory

I'm writing a program for my dad for use at his work. He basically wants a program that will go through and delete the Local User profiles because it's a fairly tedious task when 20 people log in to a computer daily. Anyway, I've got this to find all users and delete their local profiles:

```
//get a list of usernames that we don't want to get rid of
List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
string[] rawusernames = ProfileNamesTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

foreach(string user in rawusernames)
{
    usernames.Add(user.Replace("\r", ""));
}

//add default usernames that are on every (windows) machine
usernames.Add("Public");
usernames.Add("Default");
usernames.Add("Default User");
usernames.Add("All Users");

//add the current user to that list
usernames.Add(Environment.UserName);

//find the users directory
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"));

//get our machine name path
DirectoryEntry localDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName.ToString());
DirectoryEntries users = localDirectory.Children;

//for every child directory of the users directory
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.Parent.GetDirectories())
{
    //check if its a safe user name
    if(!usernames.Contains(d.Name))
    {
        //exception happens here
        DirectoryEntry user = users.Find(d.Name);
        users.Remove(user);
        user.Close();
    }
}
localDirectory.Close();
this.UseWaitCursor = false;
MessageBox.Show("All done!");
```

I'm not really sure what the error get means, I looked it up on Google but the answers seemed to be more server based than local machines. Does anyone know what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: put a breakpoint and identify from where your error comes..

Comment: @tarzanbappa I put a comment where the program actually breaks. I traced through and had no idea what the error was. The code doesn't seem to pass any bad arguments

Comment: I tried your code it works fine to me.I think there may be a issue with your directory.